# How to avoid rsync -b to backing up backup files

Tags: backup, rsync

I always do a mutual sync by issuing always "rsync -avuzb src dest" and then "rsync -avuzb dest src". If I use "rsync -avuzb  ", already existing files  are renamed to ~ on the destination, due to the b option. Now assume I have two files file and file~ on both, src and dst. The mutual sync now renames file~ to file~~ on each side. Although this is logically correct is is not practically desireble for me, since this means that the ~~~~~-files are piling up at each backup. Is there a way to only have one backup-file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this additional parameter:

```
--exclude '*~'
```

to make:

```
rsync -avuzb --exclude '*~' src dst
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem.  The ~~~ files won't pile up.  On your source folder you would typically have: a.c and a.c~
Nothing else.  Even if both files change many times the rsync folder will only have 3 files: a.c a.c~ a.c~~

Comment: Are you saying that the max number of files is three? So if OP ran that backup once more, he wont have a.c~~~? Which file gets replaced?